# Ionic Webpage error after Android apk

Tags: android, ionic-framework, ionic4

I just started Learnig Ionic and after a successful deploy of myapp (generate apk and install in my phone), i still get a web page error on my android device 'Could not connect to server (http://localhost:8080/)'

I believe the app should be offline because i haven't used any web service. check out the error [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2vZ5p.png)

Answer (score 0):

The url http://localhost:8080/ would only work on the emulator but not on an actual android device.

Find the method `webview.loadUrl()` most likely on the `MainActivity.java` and change to something like `webview.loadurl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")` instead of `webview.loadurl("http://localhost:8080/");`

Answer (score -1):

Your app *is* offline.

A plugin that all Ionic apps have been using for ages, `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`, released a new version `2.x` on July 23rd 2018. This added a webserver into the Android app that is used to deliver your app files to the webview displaying your app. It runs on `localhost:8080`.

Unfortunately version 2 of `cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` does not support Android 4.x any more which you seem to be using. This is the eason why you are getting that error message.

You can probably fix your problem by downgrading to the last version of the plugin that supported Android 4.x:

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@1.2.1
```

More elaborate information and alternative solutions:
https://ionic.zone/debug/ionic-and-android-4